# Is there anything wrong with this pattern matching code?

Tags: java, regex, string, loops

I was wondering if there was anything wrong with this code to match the pattern

```
 F_4(a,r;c,y;x,d)
```

or

```
F_4\left(a,b;b,b;\frac{-xy}{(1-y)},\frac{v}{(1-x)}\right)
```

It is supposed to match anything that has F_4(something,something;something,something;something,something) with any string or character representing something. Thanks.

```
while(line.contains("F_4")){
        Pattern appellfiv = Pattern.compile("F_4[^(]*\\(([^,]+),([^;]+);([^,]+),([^;]+);([^,]+),([^)]+)\\)");
        Matcher appellmatch = appellfiv.matcher(line);          
while(appellmatch.find())  {
                     line = appellmatch.replaceAll("\\AppellFiv@{$1}{$2}{$3}{$4}{$5}{$6}");
                }
}
```

Comment: @RohitJain, I am trying to replace all instances of this pattern with F_4{something}{something}{something}{something}{something}{something} using the matcher.find method and matcher.replaceFirst. However, it is not converting any of the instances. I thought there would be something wrong with the pattern.

Comment: Wel, your regex works on the first sample string. Are you calling the right regex functions?

Comment: You also have other general problems with this approach. Number 1 is you're re-compiling the same regex over and over. 2. You have a natural split on comma `,` so you shouldn't try to break it down with semi-colon as well, do that separately. 3. You use the `+` quantifier, should use a `*`. 4. Don't know if you have to match the whole line or not.

Comment: Does your code enter the loop? Can you explain what do you do with `line` after you create `appellmatch`?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, after I create the match, I try to replace the instance, for ex F_4(something,something;something,something;something,something), with F_4{something}{something}{something}{something}{something}{something}. I will update my code to include the replacement.

Comment: @sin, is it bad to recompile the same regex over and over? And what do you mean by natural split on comma? And I do not have to match the whole line. It is only a portion of the line that usually has a match.

Comment: @user2825125 It makes no sense to recompile the same regex. You need to compile it only once before the loop. And if you replace the content with F_4({something}...), doesn't it mean that you have infinite loop since F_4 is always there in the string?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, Oh sorry, I mistyped the replacement. I am supposed to replace it with Appell{something}{something}{something}{something}{something}{something}. Thanks.

Comment: @user2825125 Can you check your edit? I don't think `while(appellmatch.find())` is where it should belong.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, You're right, I fixed it.

Comment: @user2825125 Strange, but your code works for me. BTW, why don't you just use String.replaceAll method? `line = line.replaceAll("F_4[^(]*\\(([^,]+),([^;]+);([^,]+),([^;]+);([^,]+),([^)]+)\\)", "\\AppellFiv@{$1}{$2}{$3}{$4}{$5}{$6}");`

Answer (score 0):

Your last parameter is `\frac{v}{(1-x)}\right` and contains `)` inside it, so you cannot use `[^)]+` as regex for last parameter. You may try to use `[^,;]+` or `.+` regex for your last parameter.

**UPDATE**
The following code works for your 1st case:

```
String line = "F_4(a,r;c,y;x,d);F_4(z,p;o,q;m,n);";
line = line.replaceAll("F_4[^(]*\\(([^,]+),([^;]+);([^,]+),([^;]+);([^,]+),([^)]+)\\)", "\\AppellFiv@{$1}{$2}{$3}{$4}{$5}{$6}");
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I am using a parser for nested parentheses to solve that problem. However, if the parameter does not have nested parentheses, it still doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex you could try. Its the same functionality as yours but
reformed to relax text requirements while tightning up delimeters.

```
 #  "F_4[^(;,]*\\(([^,]*),(?:([^;,]*)(?:;([^,]*))?),(?:([^;,]*)(?:;([^,]*))?),([^)]*)\\)"

 F_4
 [^(;,]* 
 \(
 ( [^,]* )               # (1)
 ,
 (?:
      ( [^;,]* )         # (2)
      (?:
           ;
           ( [^,]* )     # (3)
      )?
 )
 ,
 (?:
      ( [^;,]* )         # (4)
      (?:
           ;
           ( [^,]* )     # (5)
      )?
 )
 ,
 ( [^)]* )               # (6)
 \)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what the "(?:"'s and ")?"'s do? And why use [^;,]* instead of [^;]*?

Comment: @user2825125 - Sure. In `[^;,]`, the not `,` is to stop from going past the next major comma delimeter, not `;` is to stop it from going past the next minor semi-colon delimeter. `(?:..)?` is an cluster group that is optional. The capture groups are still the same. Basically, if the `;` are missing, it still matches everything else, and in the correct order.